# pthread function arguments

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads

I am reading the source code of a generic C implementation of a threadpool.

The thread pool data structure is defined as:

```
typedef struct _threadpool_st{
    pthread_t *array;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t job_posted;
    pthread_cond_t job_taken;
    int arrsz;
    int live; //number of live threads in the pool
    queueHead *theQueue; //queue of work orders
} _thread_pool;
```

Then there is a function that is responsible for creating the threadpool

```
thread pool create_threadpool(int num_threads_in_pool) {
    _threadpool *pool;
    /* irrelevant initializations */
    for(i = 0; i < pool->arrest; i++){
        pthread_create(pool->array + i; NULL, do_work; (void *) pool);
        pool->live = i + 1;
        /* other stuff */
    }
    /* other stuff */
}
```

the do_work function is as follows:

```
void * do_work(void * owning_pool) {
    _threadpool *pool = (_threadpool *)owning_pool;
    int myid = pool->live;
    /* some stuff */
}
```

My understanding is that each thread in the thread pool should have its own "myid"
However, I think a race condition can happen with the way this is implemented. When a pool is created, a pthread is created that does do_work and passed a pointer to the pool data structure. All threads created are passed the same pointer to the arguments data structure. Each thread is supposed to read the value of live from that data structure. however, the main thread (the one creating the pthreads) is writing to this live variable. Is there anything I am missing here? shouldn't the live variable be protected by the pool mutex?

The full source code is here
http://people.clarkson.edu/~jmatthew/cs644.archive/cs644.fa2001/proj/pthreadsPool/

Comment: I think it's worse than that. A mutex won't ensure that the thread reads the value before the creator increments it, or that two threads don't read it between increments (they'd end up with the same `myid`).

Comment: This seems to be a fundamentally flawed design. Instead of passing a pointer to the pool to each thread, it should pass a unique structure that contains thread-specific information like its unique ID number, as well as a pointer to the common pool.

Comment: Yeah. I agree with you. I just needed confirmation because I am not very experienced with pthreads and C but I guess the args that are passed to the pthread_create should be unique

Comment: The code you're reading appears to be a student project. Any idea what grade he got?

Comment: haha no. Are you aware of any thread pool C implementation that I can reuse?

Comment: I'm sure there are plenty, but I don't know them offhand. Maybe search github.

Comment: `pool->arrest` nice typo ... ;-)